# Hide all linkbuttons with CommandArguement="value"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, command, linkbutton

Is there a way to check all linkbuttons that have a specified CommandArgument value and hide/show them in vb.net?

ex:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" class="thumbnail" style="text-align:center;" OnClick="display" CommandArgument="App1"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" class="thumbnail" style="text-align:center;" OnClick="display" CommandArgument="App2"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" class="thumbnail" style="text-align:center;" OnClick="display" CommandArgument="App1"/>
```

In vb.net I want to do the following [below is just text of what I want]

```
for each [Link buttons where CommandArguement = "App1" ]
    Linkbutton[].Visible = false
next
```

**Update:**

I tried building something like this but c.CommandArgument doesn't work.
I've done a cast on a linkbutton and got the CommandArgument from it but that was after clicking on the linkbutton and returning it which isn't the same scenario as what I am trying to accomplish.

Attempt:

```
 Dim controlId As String = ""
    Dim cControl As Control

    For Each c As Control In cControl.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is LinkButton Then
            'Or whatever that is you checking for 
            If c.commandArgument = "App1" Then

            End If

        End If
    Next
```

Example of code that works if I click on it

```
 Dim btn As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
 Dim yourValue As String = btn.CommandArgument
```

Comment: Do you want to get the CommandArgument value for any other purpose, or you're just trying to hide a specified list of controls by their CommandArgument? Seems like a good candidate for CSS/jQuery, but perhaps i'm misunderstanding your goal. You want this to happen on page load?

Comment: I have code that hides/shows Linkbuttons. They need to be hidden if the user logged in doesn't meet my criteria. I have CommandArguements that separates them from one another and thus want to hide using vb.net based on the CommandArguements. @mjw

Comment: fyi: I used the commandArguement criteria for other parts of the application so I was hoping to keep using those values to show/hide them as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the btn declaration

```
Dim c2 As Control
    For Each c2 In pnl1.Controls
        If TypeOf c2 Is LinkButton Then

            Dim btn As LinkButton = c2
            Dim val As String = btn.CommandArgument

            If val.Contains("App1") Then

            End If
        End If

    Next
```